# A composer configuration file was found at the root of your project but seems uninitialized

Tags: visual-studio-code

[Visual Studio Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Aoyu.png)

I am facing this problem when I open the Visual Studio Code. How to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are developing a project, execute

```
composer install
```

If you are developing a package, just execute

```
touch composer.lock
```